# Seaborn, subtitle placement

Tags: matplotlib, seaborn

I have a DF like that:

[image]

I’m using this code to plot a line chart.

```
plt.figure(figsize=(15,8))
sns.lineplot(predito['Day'],predito['Base_Line'], err_style=None)
sns.lineplot(predito['Day'],predito['Decision_Tree_Regressor'], err_style=None)
```

And I got that one:

[image]

How can I plot the subtitle placement on the figure?

Comment: Maybe `plt.title('My title´)`? Or `ax = sns.lineplot(...)` followed by `ax.set_title('My title')`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The subtitle you mean is actually called *legend* in matplotlib. You can either add label to each of your plotting calls or add the plots labels sequentially.

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.figure(figsize=(15,8))

index = pd.date_range("1 1 2000", periods=100,
                       freq="m", name="date")
data = np.random.randn(100, 4).cumsum(axis=0)

wide_df = pd.DataFrame(data, index, ["a", "b", "c", "d"])

sns.lineplot(data=wide_df["a"], label="a", err_style=None)
sns.lineplot(data=wide_df["b"], label="b", err_style=None)

plt.show()
```

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.figure(figsize=(15,8))

index = pd.date_range("1 1 2000", periods=100,
                       freq="m", name="date")
data = np.random.randn(100, 4).cumsum(axis=0)

wide_df = pd.DataFrame(data, index, ["a", "b", "c", "d"])

sns.lineplot(data=wide_df["a"], err_style=None)
sns.lineplot(data=wide_df["b"], err_style=None)

plt.legend(labels=['a', 'b'])

plt.show()
```

You then can set the figure's title, xlabel and ylabel with

```py
plt.title('some title')
plt.xlabel('common xlabel')
plt.ylabel('common ylabel')
```

[image]

Comment: I really appreciate your answer. I was looking for that. Many thanks.